# How can I add a checkbox to a datagrid column

Tags: livecode

Unfortunately I cannot use the DataGridHelper plugin to add a checkbox in the datagrid column since I am using the community version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add new column in the properties of the DataGridView by:

Choosing Columns from properties panel and double click on it
then choose " Add... " button
then set the new column as " Unbound Column "
Give it a name and choose its type " DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn "
Set the header you want and make sure that " read only " is not selected.
that's it.

(If the database field (in SQL Server) is of type 'bit' then the the datagridview automatically maps it to the datagridview as a checkbox instead of a textbox. No coding necessary.)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. However, I do not have all of the options you are mentioning. Picture added to original post.

Comment: I think I am closer to a solution, my datagrid seems messed up. I created a new one and can edit the template now.

Answer (score 0):

To add specific stuff to a column add a column in the property inspector, add "custom behaviour" to that column and then edit the "row template"

More details: http://lessons.runrev.com/s/3527/m/847/l/7354-customize-column-templates